# Programmatically set "Enable Parent Paths" in IIS7 from C#

Tags: c#, iis-7, asp-classic, configure

I'm trying to setup a website from a c# application and have managed to do everything except access the "ASP" settings. I would like to be able to turn "Enable Parent Paths" on for my site.

I have so far managed everything using Microsoft.Web.Administration, any help would be really appreciated?

The code i have so far is:

```
var site = sManager.Sites.Add(webSite.SiteName, webSite.PhysicalLocation, webSite.Port);
site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = webSite.ApplicationPoolName;
site.Bindings.Clear();
site.Bindings.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", webSite.BindingIP, webSite.Port, webSite.HostHeader), "http");

site.ServerAutoStart = true;
sManager.CommitChanges();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this [AspSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347544%28v=vs.90%29) topic in MSDN and also some [basic how to on web adminstrator](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/).  Although the "how to" doesn't actually demonstrate it you should be able to cast a section to the `AspSection` class:

```
        Configuration config = sManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        AspSection section = (AspSection)config.GetSection("system.webServer/asp",webSite.SiteName);
        section.EnableParentPaths = true;
```

if some reason the cast is not allowed you can use the basic attribute approach:

```
        Configuration config = sManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("system.webServer/asp",webSite.SiteName);
        ConfigurationAttribute enableParentPaths = section.GetAttribute("enableParentPaths");
        enableParentPaths.Value = true;
```

Comment: Excellent yes your second example worked a treat, thanks for the quick help!